# python regular expression match a pattern

Tags: python, regex

So, I have been trying to match a simple pattern like `B0000001` where just the first character be an alphabet "`B`" and rest should be numbers. The total length should be 9.

I tried the pattern `"^B[0-9]{7}$"` but it fails most of the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Total length should be 8 or 9?

Comment: For me your example works?? I'v tried: `re.match('^B[0-9]{7}$','B0000001')`

Answer (score 2):

Use this expresion:

```
^B\d{8}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/brTleq/2)